# How to sync deleted photos with google photos/drive?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sync, photos, gallery

Have in mind that when I take photos I might take 2 shots of same instance. I arrive home, start wi-fi. All photos are synced with photos.
Now - looking into gallery I delete some of them - they were bad photos.
How can I make sure that when I delete an image it is also removed from photos application?

Comment: Try using [folder sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). One of the reviews has your use case (by Anssi)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Gallery to manage your photos. Use the Google Photos app to manage your photos on your device, when you delete a photo in the Photo app it is deleted from all attached devices as well, including locally and the Google Photo storage.

Comment: but still then the photos from gallery(so real files on device) won't be removed, right?

Comment: @AlexaAdrian Not on my Moto G3 with Marshmallow... If I delete a picture in the Photo app, it deletes it from the device (thus Gallery as well), Drive/Photo account, and all linked/synced devices. Tested and verified.